# How to Convert Firebase data to Java Object...?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using Firebase Library to send data to the server in the form `Message(String, String)` added to the `HashMap<String, Message>`

Example:

```
Firebase fb = new Firebase(URL);
Firebase msgRef = fb.child("finished");
HashMap<String, Message> msgList = new HashMap<>();
Message msg = new Message(m, n);
msgList.put(HASHKEY, msg);
msgRef.push().setValue(msgList);
```

While receiving data with Firebase method `addValueEventListener()` getting String in this Form

```
{ key = finished, value = {
    -Js9Rn0uttjYIGdcv8I1={Moosa={message=email, name=Kamran}},
    -Js9Vsmv6BnVzOzpl2L8={Moosa={message=msgs, name=Imran}}, 
    -Js9WtQ8yeDwVxQMFCZb={Moosa={message=samsung, name=Samad}}, 
    -Js9RarxoJPKn4RO2HaM={Moosa={message=Message, name=Moosa}}, 
    -Js9b6f75lwwbsqQNJz0={Moosa={message=Qmobile, name=Bilal}}, 
    -Js9aDxt8TlgTGUccuxu={Moosa={message=last, name=Moosa}}} }
```

How can I convert it into Message Object.....????

Answer (score 126, accepted):

There are two more way to get your data out of the Firebase `DataSnapshot` that don't require using a `Map<String, Object>`.

First appoach is to **use the methods of `DataSnapshot`** to traverse the children:

```
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages").limitToLast(10);
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = (String) messageSnapshot.child("name").getValue();
            String message = (String) messageSnapshot.child("message").getValue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { }
});
```

In the above snippet we use `getChildren()` to get an `Iterable` of your messages. Then we use `child("name")` to get each specific child property.

The second approach is to **use the built-in JSON-to-POJO serializer/deserializer**. When you're sending the message list, the `Message` objects inside it are serialized to JSON and stored in Firebase.

To get them out of it again, you have to do the inverse:

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Message message = messageSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { }
});
```

In this second snippet, we're still using `getChildren()` to get at the messages, but now we deserialize them from JSON straight back into a `Message` object.

For a simple sample application using that last approach, have a look at [Firebase's AndroidChat sample](https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat/). It also shows how to efficiently deal with the list of messages (hint: `FirebaseListAdapter`).

Comment: In your second approach how is the firebase data mapped to the properties of the pojo? Does the pojo property name and the firebase node name exactly needs to match with each other?

Comment: @ParagKadam yes, as long they have same field names.

Comment: What if the attributes like "name" and "message" are dynamic. how to get data snapshot and generate a object. Convert Json Object into Java object direcly.

Comment: You could get the values into a `Map<String,Object>`. But I recommend against that. If the objects are dynamic, you're better off sticking to the `DataSnapshot` itself.

Answer (score 11):

So if you wanna get the messages you can do the following:

```
        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
    //child is each element in the finished list
    Map<String, Object> message = (Map<String, Object>)child.getValue();
    Message msg = new Message((String) message.getValue().get("message"),
            (String) message.get("name"));
}
```

Comment: Its returning the null value in both conditions...
dataSnapshot.getValue();
child.getValue();

Comment: can you show the request your send to firebase??also what method are you using to retrive the data `onDataChange` or `onChildAdded`??

Comment: `Firebase msgRef = fb.child("messagebox");
        HashMap<String, Message> msgList = new HashMap<>();
        Message msg = new Message(m, n);
        msgList.put("Moosa", msg);
        msgRef.push().setValue(msgList);`

Comment: ok can you check the `dataSnapshot` and the `child` values and print them

Comment: DATASNAPSHOT --->
`{-Js9Rn0uttjYIGdcv8I1={Moosa={message=email, name=Kamran}}, -Js9Vsmv6BnVzOzpl2L8={Moosa={message=msgs, name=Imran}}, -Js9WtQ8yeDwVxQMFCZb={Moosa={message=samsung, name=Samad}}, -Js9RarxoJPKn4RO2HaM={Moosa={message=Message, name=Moosa}}, -Js9b6f75lwwbsqQNJz0={Moosa={message=Qmobile, name=Bilal}}, -Js9aDxt8TlgTGUccuxu={Moosa={message=last, name=Moosa}}}`

Comment: Child Values- Iterating -->
`{Moosa={message=Message, name=Moosa}}
{Moosa={message=email, name=Kamran}}
{Moosa={message=msgs, name=Imran}}
{Moosa={message=samsung, name=Samad}}
{Moosa={message=last, name=Moosa}}
{Moosa={message=Qmobile, name=Bilal}}`

Comment: so you got the children, the only thing here is just one more step let me update the answer

Comment: got it using nested for loop and iterating the child values with the help of above solution.... 
Thnx Bro....

Comment: Well why did you add Moosa as a key for the messages?? because that what made you get the child as a map then get the message from the map which key is Moosa

Comment: No Reason... It's my name... :)

Answer (score 9):

Iterating the values of dataSnapshot and getting Children using nested for loop to iterate the child elements of children and getting the Required Value...

```
for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot single : child.getChildren()) {
                        Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) single.getValue();
                        String a = (String) map.get("message");
                        String b = (String) map.get("name");
                        textView.append(b + " -- " + a + "\n");
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this code if you want to convert firebase object to json using Gson Library :

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Object object = dataSnapshot.getValue(Object.class);
            String json = new Gson().toJson(object);
            Example example= new Gson().fromJson(json, Example.class);
            Log.e("json","json: " + example.getGlossary());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

This will convert complete Database Structure to String json and then json to class object using Gson Lib

Answer (score 2):

You could make it using a `ChildEventListener` instead of a `ValueEventListener`.

For example. I have a class called match with 3 string properties `{id, name, photoUrl}` then I add all the values in a `List`. Instead of using a for loop it works for me with this code.

```
    Query queryRef = mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("matches");

    ChildEventListener listener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            Match match = dataSnapshot.getValue(Match.class);
            matchList.add(match);
            mAdapter = new MatchAdapter(getContext(), matchList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            Log.d("MESSAGEFRAGMENT", "CHILDCHANGE");
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    queryRef.addChildEventListener(listener);
```