# Getting a list of items from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Lets say i have two model classes.

```
class School {
  ArrayList<Students> students;
  public ArrayList<Students> getStudents() {
   return students;
  }      

}

class Students {
  String studentName;
  public String getStudent() {
    return studentName;
  }
}
```

This is how i store the data:
[image]

How would i go by retrieving the students? I've tried this, but it does not work.

```
mRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            School s1 = datasnapshot.getValue(School.class)
            s1.getStudents();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you made sure that myRef points exactly where you want it to be?

Comment: sout(mRef) prints out firebase_url/school, so yes. Is the code above supposed to work?

Comment: Have you tried using `Hashmap<String,Object> someVariable` and then use `somevariable.getValue()`
Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30933328/how-to-convert-firebase-data-to-java-object) if above does not work