# How to convert firebase data (snake_case) to Java object (camelCase)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, type-conversion

I want to map my firebase data object to my pojo. However, my firebase object property name is snake case, 
such as; "user_name". 
I want to use camelCase on my pojo, 
such as; "userName"

I found beautiful answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30933328/how-to-convert-firebase-data-to-java-object) one, however, I couldn't find any sample about snake_case to camelCase mapping.

My pojo;

```
@SerializedName("content")
private String content;
@SerializedName("user_name")
private String userName;
```

I'm using the following line of code for mapping. 'content' matches with no problem(with or without @SerializedName annotation) but userName stays as null.

`Story story = storySnapshot.getValue(Story.class);`

That is also an issue for obfuscation. Is there an elegant way to match the data to pojo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was @SerializedName annotation. Firebase has its own annotation, which is @PropertyName.

It is important to be careful about getter name because annotation cares about its name too. 
The property must be public too.

There is a perfect answer about that on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38681260/firebase-propertyname-doesnt-work) link.

Final state of my pojo;

```
@PropertyName("content")
public String content;
@PropertyName("user_name")
public String userName;
```

Comment: Awesome, been searching for this!