# what is the idiom to query a Firebase DatabaseReference?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**not** an android question.

Method intended to query the database:

```
private void db() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("serviceAccountKey.json");
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl(stringURL)
            .build();

    log.info(options.toString());

    FirebaseApp firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    FirebaseDatabase f = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(firebaseApp, stringURL);

    DatabaseReference databaseNonRoot = f.getReference();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = databaseNonRoot.getRoot();

    log.info(databaseReference.toString());

    //    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
    //really?
}
```

I've entered data [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872774/populate-firebase-with-initial-and-arbitrary-objects?rq=1) through the web interface.  How do I query Firebase?  Something analogous to `SELECT * FROM <TABLE>` is what I'm looking for.

JSON data export:

```
{
  "abc" : 123,
  "bar" : 4342342,
  "foo" : 432434
}
```

see also:

[how to get all child list from Firebase android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886546/how-to-get-all-child-list-from-firebase-android/36600791#36600791)

Comment: In general interacting with the Firebase Database is the same between Android and other Java environments. Reading lists of data is explained here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events and here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-event-types What does your data structure look like (as JSON text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I'll update momentarily with JSON.  If I can get the JSON tree that will get me headed in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Really.

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      System.out.println("Key="+childSnapshot.getKey()+" Value="+childSnapshot.getValue());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    throw databaseError.toException();
  }
});
```

See the [Firebase documentation on dealing with lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#read_and_write_lists) for more information. I also recommend reading my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30943084/209103

Comment: does this only listen for changes or does it query the actual JSON tree in its entirety?

Comment: The `onDataChange` fires for the initial data and for any subsequent change.