# Why am I getting the Invocation Target Exception while using Firebase Recycler View Adapter?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NoteModel, NoteViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NoteModel, NoteViewHolder>(
        NoteModel.class,
        R.layout.note_card,
        NoteViewHolder.class,
        fNotesDatabase) {
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(final NoteViewHolder viewHolder, NoteModel model, int position) {
        final String noteId = getRef(position).getKey();

        Log.e("MainActivity","Populate View");

        fNotesDatabase.child(noteId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("mTitle") && dataSnapshot.hasChild("mTime")) {
                    String title = dataSnapshot.child("mTitle").getValue().toString();
                    String timestamp = dataSnapshot.child("mTime").getValue().toString();
                    String content =  dataSnapshot.child("mContent").getValue().toString();

                    GetTimeAgo getTimeAgo = new GetTimeAgo();
                    viewHolder.setTime(getTimeAgo.getTimeAgo(Long.parseLong(timestamp), getApplicationContext()));

                    viewHolder.setTitle(title);
                    //viewHolder.setNoteTime(timestamp);
                    viewHolder.setContent(content);
                    viewHolder.setTime(timestamp);
                    Log.e("MainActivity","Data retrieval"+title);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
};
recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

This is inside a function named `loadData()` in my `MainActivity` why am I getting the `InvocationTargetException`?

The Firebase Instance is declared in the `onCreate()` function of the `MainActivity`.

Where's the problem, because I'm guessing I've added all the necessary code.

Here's the logcat:

```
09-29 19:46:31.266 7997-7997/com.dell.noteit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.dell.noteit, PID: 7997
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:202)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6493)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5680)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:556)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1710)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:346)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:959)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:734)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:667)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:945)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:198)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6493) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5680) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:556) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1710) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:346) 
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:959) 
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:734) 
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:667) 
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:945) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.dell.noteit.NoteViewHolder cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener
    at com.dell.noteit.NoteViewHolder.<init>(NoteViewHolder.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
    at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:198) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6493) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5680) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:556) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1710) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:346) 
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:959) 
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:734) 
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:667) 
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:945) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at 

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 

            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386) 
    09-29 19:46:31.317 7997-7997/com.dell.noteit I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7997 SIG: 9
```

Here's the NoteViewHolder File.

```
NoteViewHolder.java

public class NoteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public  ImageView image;
    public int imageView;
    public TextView title;
    public TextView content;
    public String color;
    public  TextView time;
    public View mview;
    public CardView notecard;


    public NoteViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mview = itemView;
        itemView.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_title);
        content = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_content);
        time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_timestamp);
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_image);
        notecard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title.getText().toString();
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title.setText((CharSequence) title);
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content.getText().toString();
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content.setText((CharSequence) content);
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time.getText().toString();
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time.setText(time);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste your logcat too

Comment: Please add the exact and complete stack trace to your question and responde with @.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท I've added the logcat

Comment: Add your NoteViewHolder code.

Comment: Please also add the content of your `build.gradle` file and please responde with @AlexMamo.

Comment: @TheWanderer I've added the NoteViewHolder.java code

Comment: @WaveMetric check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're casting your `NoteViewHolder` to an `OnClickListener`. You can't do that, because it doesn't implement that class.

If you want to use `this` for the `OnClickListener`, add `implements View.OnClickListener` after `extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder`. Then remove the casting when you set the listener.

You'll also need:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //What you want to happen on the click event
}
```

In your `ViewHolder` class.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

I didn't see ***class cast exception*** in the logcat:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.dell.noteit.NoteViewHolder cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener
```

It seems like you're casting `NoteViewHolder` to `View$OnClickListener` which mentioned by the Wonderer too and I've made some changes to your codes which might help.

This would be fine for your `ViewHolder`:

```
public class NoteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    private ImageView image;   /// make all of them private
    private TextView title;
    private TextView content;
    private String color;
    private TextView time;
    private View mview;
    private CardView notecard;


    public NoteViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this); // Here might cause issues too!
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_title);
        content = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_content);
        time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_timestamp);
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_image);
        notecard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
    }
```

For getters-setters, use model and those should be like this (As an example):

```
public final class User {

    private String mName;
    private String mEmail;

    public String getTitle() { return mName; }
    ...
    ..
```

You can find a good one in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48037074/4409113

Android Studio creates them automatically by using `Alt+ Insert` for Windows: [How to automatically generate getters and setters in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897215/how-to-automatically-generate-getters-and-setters-in-android-studio)

Comment: Their ViewHolder doesn't implement OnClickListener, but they're casting a `this` argument to it. Hence the ClassCastException farther down the log. See my answer.

Comment: I don't really see any other issues. The getters and setters seem fine to me. I am on my phone though.

Comment: I don't see how any of these would cause errors. setText takes a CharSequence and String implements that. It's just a redundant cast. Same for mView: just redundant. imageView is unused. image is the ImageView variable.

Comment: Oh my mistake. I didn't actually see-check that *class cast exception*. However, Updated the answer.