# Android : com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String

Tags: java, android

```
private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
{
    spacecrafts.clear();

    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
    {
        Spacecraft spacecraft=ds.getValue(Spacecraft.class);
        spacecrafts.add(spacecraft);
    }
}
```

`Spacecraft spacecraft=ds.getValue(Spacecraft.class);` *This line returns below error*

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object
>   of type java.lang.String to type
>   lk.magesty.covidnewssrilanka.m_Model.Spacecraft

Anyone know a solution for this ?

Spacecraft.java file

```
package lk.magesty.covidnewssrilanka.m_Model;

public class Spacecraft {
    String name,propellant,description;


    public Spacecraft(){
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPropellant() {
        return propellant;
    }

    public void setPropellant(String propellant) {
        this.propellant = propellant;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show Spacecraft.java?

Comment: Updated that to Question dude. Please check @AmitB10

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30933328/how-to-convert-firebase-data-to-java-object?

Comment: Thats now working for me

Comment: Did you use same solution in the link?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Convert Firebase data to Java Object...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30933328/how-to-convert-firebase-data-to-java-object)